# Android SQLite, database multiple tables, column not being created

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I am trying to create two tables, with a key of one table being a key on another table so that I can make one row to many.  Here is my oncreate code.

```
private static final String MESSAGE_TABLE_CREATE =
        "CREATE TABLE " + MESSAGE_HISTORY + " (" +
                MSG_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                TASK_ID + " INTEGER, " +
                RECEIVER + " TEXT, " +
                SENDER + " TEXT, " +
                CHAT_MSG + " TEXT, " +
                SHOWUTCDATE + " TEXT, " +
                FLAG + " TEXT, " +
                NEWTIMESTAMP + " TEXT, " +
                LAT + " TEXT, " +
                LON + " TEXT, " +
                IMAGE_URL + " TEXT, " +
                DESTINATION + " TEXT, " +
                ATTACHMENT_ID + " TEXT, " +
                MIME + " TEXT, " +
                SIZE + " TEXT, " +
                EXTENSION + " TEXT, " +
                IS_ACCEPTED + " TEXT, " +
                USER_ID + " TEXT " +
                ")";

private static final String VENDOR_TABLE_CREATE =
        "CREATE TABLE " + VENDORS + " (" +
                VENDOR_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " +
                TASK_ID + "INTEGER, " +
                RECEIVER + " TEXT, " +
                SENDER + " TEXT, " +
                VENDOR_NAME + " TEXT, " +
                VENDOR_CONTENT + " TEXT, " +
                VENDOR_STAR + " TEXT, " +
                VENDOR_ADDRESS + " TEXT, " +
                VENDOR_COMMENTS + " TEXT, " +
                VENDOR_DISTANCE + " TEXT, " +
                MOBILE + " TEXT, " +
                PHONE + " TEXT, " +
                LAT + " TEXT, " +
                LON + " TEXT, " +
                JUDESAYS + " TEXT " +
                ")";


public TasksDBOpenHelper (Context context){
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db){
    db.execSQL(CURRENT_TABLE_CREATE);
    db.execSQL(HISTORY_TABLE_CREATE);
    db.execSQL(MESSAGE_TABLE_CREATE);
    db.execSQL(VENDOR_TABLE_CREATE);
}
```

For some reason, on the vendors table the column "TASK_ID" is not being created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a space between `TASK_ID` & the word `INTEGER`.

Should be `TASK_ID + " INTEGER, " +`